# Changing header bar colour on Chrome for Android does not work

Tags: mobile, android-manifest, manifest, head

I am trying to change the header / search bar menu colour on mobiles for a website with the below code within the `<head>` tags.

```
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#313131">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#00f800">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#00f800">
```

This however is not working for me and so have tried also with the mobile manifest json file placing this in the header:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
```

Where `manifest.json` is like below:

```
{
  "short_name": "Maps",
  "name": "Google Maps",
  "icons": [
  {
   "src": "/images/icons-192.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  },
  {
    "src": "/images/icons-512.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }
  ],
  "start_url": "/maps/?source=pwa",
  "background_color": "#3367D6",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/maps/",
  "theme_color": "#3367D6"
}
```

This has also not worked so have checked over stackoverflow and noticed that not having a valid ssl certificate may also be a cause and so added one to the site however am still getting the same issue.

The colour does change slightly to a darker grey so does seem to do something however not the colour I am after. I have used a range of hex codes from examples on here as well as from sites that I can see working on the same mobile I am testing on so do not believe it is a problem with the mobile or the colours being used.

I'm wondering if there are any other causes for this now working?